Handling Unsuccessful Checkouts with Chargebee: Missing Events and Status Updates
I’m using Chargebee’s hosted pages for managing subscriptions, and I’ve noticed that successful checkouts trigger events such as subscription_created, which I can handle in my application. However, I’m encountering an issue with unsuccessful checkouts. Specifically, I’m not receiving any events or status updates when a checkout fails.
What happens when a checkout is unsuccessful on Chargebee?
Is there a way to ensure that I get notified or can handle scenarios where the checkout fails or is canceled by the user?
I attempted to listen for events from Chargebee that could indicate the status of unsuccessful checkouts. Specifically, I was looking for events or status updates that would help me handle failed checkouts programmatically.
Despite setting up event listeners, I did not receive any events related to unsuccessful checkouts, such as failures or cancellations.

One of the ways to handle this is to enable Abandoned Cart tracking. Once you have this enabled, you can retrieve the hosted pages using List Hosted Pages API with a filter like state[is]=requested (which means the end user had visited the page). checkout_info object would contain checkout_submit with a status field to indicate whether the checkout succeeded or failed. If it had failed, checkout_submit object will contain errors with more info on what went wrong.

So does chargebee not send any event in case of payment failure?
